# How start from "end of content" (bottom) in Overflow include during loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, css

During page loading and finished loading, I want my Overflow fixed `<div>` always started right at the bottom - end of the content. What is important to me that it really must started at the bottom immediately, and NOT during loading the content will be displayed at the top, and after completion of loading it jumps down. For example, same as if you open chat in Facebook.

Then I needed to use the "Infinite Ajax Scrolling" system to operate in the opposite direction, ie if I scroll up and not down to show more and more content. How to do it in this case?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you can accept to load the contents in the revers order, then you can easily achieve the desired result with this:

```
display: -webkit-flex;
-webkit-flex-direction: column-reverse;
```

The scroll depends on on the direction.

See example, including a basic infinite scroll: http://jsfiddle.net/frapporti/vz46W/

Comment: Wow, I've never seen this before. It support all main browsers or only webkit? Thanks man

Comment: Yes, you can add other prefixes to support other modern browsers, plus you can add the older box method (2009), to support others as well. Also, if you add 2009 method, you can add also a js that acts automatically as polyfill for even older browsers. The cool thing is that currently with the fall of win XP, the percentage of IE users that are upgrading really allow us to fearlessly embrace the power of HTML5. We now live in the long awaited golden era of web development.

Comment: Feel free to ask me for a full example ;)

Comment: sure! first thing, apply an overflow: scroll to the <ul> element, then we'll see if there's something else

Comment: OK, now is overflow on <ul>.

Comment: yes, but i don't have your link anymore.. perhaps you deleted your posts? i thought you figured out

Comment: nvm, this isnt working for me anyway, Im looking for something else what will works

Comment: If you like, I'd still like to check your issue.